# Is it okay to listen to Quranic recitation with the Quran open in front of you?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, translation

I'm not that confident with my recitation so I put on the recitation on audio and opened the Quran and instead of reciting it myself I listened while also keeping my attention on the page. During the recitation, I followed the progress with my eyes as well. I'm wondering if its okay to do that

Comment: @UmH for the first part of the question this actually applies.

Comment: @Medi1Saif There is more than one part?

Comment: @UmH IMHO "During the recitation, I followed the progress with my eyes as well. I'm wondering if its okay to do that" should be taken into account.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Am I missing something? As far as I can tell she is listening to a recording of the recitation while simultaneously looking at the words in a mushaf, so as to learn their pronunciation. It is a learning technique, she is not performing prayer or making recitation herself.